# Auto call without asking the user

Tags: java, mobile, symbian

I am developing a java mobile application. Its purpose is that, when installed, it reacts to SMS messages on a specific port (suppose 5000) and the reaction is to make a call to a predefined number already installed in the application.

When I try to do that, a confirmation is requested before the call is made.

Is there a way to avoid this confirmation prompt?

Comment: I seriously hope not.  Imagine the implications of an app able to automatically make a call to a premium rate number without asking the user for confirmation.

Comment: It is for security purpose. Suppose you have lost your phone then you want to track it. It is a good thing to call from your phone to a specific number. I want to remotely access my phone that's all.I think I am clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in Symbian phones. I'm not so sure about Java apps.

```
        CTelephony::TTelNumber telNumber(_L("+9001123456")); 
    CTelephony::TCallParamsV1 callParams;    
    callParams.iIdRestrict = CTelephony::ESendMyId;  
    CTelephony::TCallParamsV1Pckg callParamsPckg(callParams);  
    iTelephony->DialNewCall(iStatus, callParamsPckg, telNumber, iCallId);  
    SetActive();
```

Comment: how? Can you tell me? symbian will do. I want it for my s60 phone.

Answer (score 3):

It is (hopefully) not possible, to start a call without confirmation. You could create a "money-making-maschine" by sending SMS to a phone and let them call a number with high costs.

Comment: No one can not. It is only possible when the application is installed on that phone and with a predefined number installed with it. Do you get my point.

Comment: Point is that while you may be honest and not call to premium rate numbers then other developers may do it. Thats why normally these API calls are missing or restricted to normal developers.